# How to develop a program that install SQL Express and add a database in it

Tags: .net, windows-installer, sql-server-express

I would need to create a program that only install SQL Express and install a database at the same time (either from a bak or mdf, whichever is prefered) At the end of the creation, this program would generate a text file.

I found on the web how to install SQL Express, but I can't seem to find anything to add a database after the installation.

So far I don't have anything to install else than that because the application that will use the application will be installed on another machine.

Thanks

Comment: Because we want a SQL Server, not a file base database. Since not all people already have one, it'll be Express in those case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple way would be to make a simple batch file, with a line to run the SQL Express command line install and then the next to run `sqlcmd` to do the restore.

[How to: Install SQL Server 2008 R2 from the Command Prompt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259.aspx)

[Backup and Restore Your SQL Server Database from the Command Line](http://www.howtogeek.com/50295/backup-your-sql-server-database-from-the-command-line/)

If you want to make your life easier then use some kind of installer tool. I have used [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/), [InstallAware](http://www.installaware.com/), and [InstallShield](http://www.flexerasoftware.com/products/installshield.htm) at various times to do this.